# How to start location tracking based on GPS number of satellites?

Tags: android, location

How could I get and use the number of satellites before starting location tracking?

For example I want to start location tracking only when there are min X satellites in use.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do? Why do you need a minimum number of satellites? Just because you have X satellites doesn't guarantee you accurate results. If you're trying to conserve battery, checking for active satellites until you find the requisite number is probably more draining than just registering a location listener and letting it do its thing

Comment: It's in the specs of the software I am creating. Suppose I register the location listener, do I get how many satellites have been used?

Answer (score 2):

See the answer I gave you to your other question - [How to measure GPS signal strength on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551697/how-to-measure-gps-signal-strength-on-android/3551743#3551743).

Basically, `LocationManager.getGpsStatus().getSatellites()`.

And again, personally I don't think that going on this level is a good idea for a location-based app, unless you specifically need to do something with the satellite data.