# How to measure GPS signal strength on Android?

Tags: android, location

Question is as simple as the title: How to measure GPS signal strength?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you sure you mean signal strength vs. accuracy? What good is the signal strength? Since the GPS position is determined via many satellites, you don't have "one" signal strength.

So assuming that you really mean signal strength, you can get the `GpsStatus` via `LocationManager.getGpsStatus()`, and that gives you a list of satellites via `getSatellites()`', and each one of those has a signal-to-noise ratio (`getSnr()`).

Assuming you mean accuracy, try `Location.getAccuracy()`.

Comment: Take a look into this article Enhancing the Code to Measure GPS Signal Strength Read more: http://www.brighthub.com/electronics/gps/articles/42995.aspx#ixzz0xV3QAuOh Is that possible on Android?

Comment: Just to point that `getSatellites` might return 0 satellites in some implementations (in Gingerbread in particular); in this case you'd have to resort to NMEA string parsing.

Comment: how accuracy is calculated? doesn't it use the satellites's signal strength too?

Comment: How much is the minimum number of satellites needed to consider a "good signal"?

Comment: it's deprecated, now its `GnssStatus` and there is not such method as `getSatellites()`

Answer (score 0):

You can read signal strength in MNEA message GSV in SNR-Signal to Noise Ratio.

Signal strength is VERY important. Too weak of a signal and the receiver can't track them.  You need  several  'strong' satellites to get position, not just one.

Older receivers couldn't track in trees or inside buildings. Modern receivers are much more sensitive.

Answer (score -2):

It is very difficult to measure the signal level of a gps satellite without very expensive test gear (spectrum analyzer or specialized gps receiver).  There are no commercially available tools to do this.

Why would you want to do this, anyway?  The signal level is actually quite irrelevant in determining position.

Comment: It's the exact requirement for this product.