# Android:Determine the GPS signal strength

Tags: android, gps

My app will determine the current location accurately using `GPS`,`Cellular network`or `WiFi`.If `GPS`signal strength is poor or low then the accuracy will be poor so i have to turn off `GPS` and switch `cellular network` or `WiFi`.
My challenge is

1.How can i determine the `GPS` signal is poor or strong. If poor i need to stop `GPS` and switch to `cellular network` or `WiFi`?

2.If `GPS` signal is strong how can i confirm that location is accurate and run `locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);` to stop update?

3.Battery consumption should be minimum.

Thank you advance for any suggestion or code.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551697/how-to-measure-gps-signal-strength-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request locations from all providers (GPS, Cellular & Wifi) at once.  The locations delivered give information on type of fix and also information on what the estimated accuracy of the fix is.

So you can turn further updates off when you have checked the results you have already received.

Battery to get cellular and WiFi fixes is very very low, so if you have GPS on at all I would not worry about also turning on cellular and WiFi to get fix at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer your first query. To determine GPS signal strength use the below code:

> getGsmSignalStrength();

```
private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    /* Get the Signal strength from the provider, each time there is an update */
    @Override
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
    {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go to Firstdroid!!! GSM Cinr = "
                + String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

};
```

I hope this helps.