# GPS Signal Strength

Tags: android, gps, location, spoofing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to measure GPS signal strength on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551697/how-to-measure-gps-signal-strength-on-android)

Is there a way to measure or determine the strength (and perhaps further propoerties) of the gps signal for each gps satellite in view on a android smartphone? The API does only offer information about SNR and the location. I wrote a small NMEA parser, but in the NMEA sentences i am receiving there are no information about the several signals either...

So, is there a way to measure the signal? Or is there a library or project which is dealing with this topic?

I need the signal strength (**not** the location, the accuracy or the SNR) for some experiments on anti gps spoofing techniques.

best regards,
htz

Comment: [This question has been asked many times before.](https://www.google.com/#q=gps+signal+strength+android+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Yes, and there was no sufficient answer to this question. My question aims on the signal strength... not the SNR, not the accuracy and not the location. As you can see, every answer is related to one of these topics, but i do not need these things.