# Any alternative to onNmeaReceived?

Tags: android, nmea

I have written an app that uses NMEA data, provided by NmeaListener. This app works perfectly on following devices:

- Asus Nexus 7, Android 4.1.1
- Samsung Nexus S, Android 4.1.2
- SonyEricsson Xperia Mini, Android 2.3.4
- SonyEricsson Xperia X10 Mini, Android 2.1.1

On all those devices, the onNmeaReceived() is called with no problem.

But on the low cost device

- Huawei/Vodafone 858, Android 2.2.2

onNmeaReceived()  is not called at all. At least onLocationChanged() is called on all devices, including the Huawei. But I don't need the location, I need the NMEA data.

So, what can I do?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
public class Main extends Activity implements NmeaListener, LocationListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LocationManager location = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    location.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1l, 1l, this);
    location.addNmeaListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
}
```

Comment: As far as I can remember, even in devices receiving NMEA sentences the types of sentences received will vary. What do you need the NMEA string for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue if you look at this thread:

[Issue 7321: NmeaListener does not receive nmea sentences](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7321)

if this is affecting you there is probably no other solution than generating fake NMEA from the location updates, at least on the affected phones.

[Edit]

From your comment it seems that you assume you need NmeaListener in order to display info like signal strengths and Satellites, but I think you can do this without NmeaListener, just look at the answers to:

[How to measure GPS signal strength on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551697/how-to-measure-gps-signal-strength-on-android)

Comment: This issue cannot be the problem: There are apps running on this device which can show signal strength of any satellite in view/use. Since you cannot extract this info from the location, there must be another solution. ;-)

Comment: Maybe those other apps use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551697/how-to-measure-gps-signal-strength-on-android) to display signal strength instead of NMEA data?

Comment: Yes... I think that's the way "they" do it.Thank you!