# How to handle GPS under roof in Android

Tags: android, gps

I have created application that gets a relevant lat and long and updates in a database. The problem is that when I under a roof like house or mall... I keep getting the GPS searching ICON on my app.

I am using a button to trigger the Mylocation() and it's listener.

The button has the following:

```
locationListener = new MyLocationListener();                        
location.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, locationListener);
```

and under the mylocationlistener method I have

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location: Lat:" + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng:" + loc.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            location.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            location = null;
            finish();
          }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
```

I get the value toasted properly without any problem and app is finished an GPS icon goes away but when I am inside the roof and GPS icon in top keeps searching for GPS. The icon doesn't go away.

How do I fix this? Do I need to put a condition if Gps signal is good start the GPS if not just message GPS signal not good. if so how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As described in this question [How to measure GPS signal strength on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551697/how-to-measure-gps-signal-strength-on-android),

> So assuming that you really mean signal strength, you can get the `GpsStatus` via `LocationManager.getGpsStatus()`, and that gives you a list of satellites via `getSatellites()`, and each one of those has a signal-to-noise ratio (`getSnr()`)

Comment: I put the following inside On Click:

GpsStatus gpsStatus = location.getGpsStatus(null);     if(gpsStatus != null)
{
  locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
  location.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, locationListener);
}else{
locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
location.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 5,locationListener);}

No changes does the same stuff like before?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the network location service as well as or instead of GPS. You could also consider adding a timeout.