# how many GPS satellites can be search by handset?

Tags: gps

These days I play google ingress, but sometimes My phone can not location,I try to use gps tools to test my phone, only 10 satellites can be searched.

I compare my phone with samsung galaxy S3.

My phone can search 10 satellites, in good signal area.
   But Samsung galaxy S3 can search 16 satellites although in good signal area or bad signal area.

16 satellites? what is the max number of GPS satelites can be search ?

thanks

Comment: some smartphones also can use the russian GLONASS sattelites. then theoretically it can be more then the 16 GPS sattelites in view.

Comment: @AlexWien galaxy S3 use both gps chip and GLONASS chip inside。 its gps is quite good。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what type of phone you have, but the number will depend on how many GPS receiver channels are implemented in your phone chipset.

You can find out how many GPS satellites are availeable at http://www.navcen.uscg.gov/?Do=constellationstatus. Currently there are 31. I guess about half these are over the horizon so you wouldn't expect to see more than 16. I know of some GPS receivers that could handle up to 66 satellites.

Comment: Some gps chip can search more than 16 satellites。this is SiRFstarIII http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SiRFstarIII

Answer (score 3):

Having 16 GPS satellites in view at the same time should be very rare (see user2151446's answer). 10 satellites should be plenty for an excellent fix though -- anything above 5-6 satellites is enough for a precise position *in theory*.

In practice however, often the more important factors are

- Relative position of the visible satellites: if all of them are in the same region of the sky, triangulation won't yield very precise results. With more than 5 satellites in view this is very unlikely however. See [Dilution of Precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_%28GPS%29).
- Signal to Noise ratio (SNR): if the received signal from the satellites is weak, the calculated position will be pretty inaccurate as well. Also bad SNR is an indicator for:
- Signal reflections: If the signal is reflected from buildings etc, it will give the receiver misleading information. In the city this can be a pretty common problem.

Signal strength info is rather hard to get. On Android the "NMEA Recorder" app gives you a good view of the detailed GPS data as well as a log of the raw [NMEA data](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm), but I'm not sure if it includes the SNR info.

Edit: This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3551697/1814922) contains info on how to get the SNR programmatically.

Edit 2: The app [GPS Status & Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus) displays "signal strength" indicators (use it in horizontal layout). With some trying in good/bad reception areas this should give you a pretty good indication of what the situation actually is.