# Android: locationManager GPS_provider VS Network_provider

Tags: android, geolocation, android-gps

I have these two lines of code ready to be used in the section of my app where the user's location is requested:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);
```

**The problem is** that, when testing in real device, I have noticed that, using `GPS_provider` does not work very well when being in certain places like inside of a building....the app is stuck waiting to acquire GPS coordinates which take a lot of time or just never come unless I have open-sky conditions.

**The question would be**: how do I do to still use `GPS_provider`by default but, if gps coordinates take more than XXXX seconds to be acquired, then switch to `Network_provider`and acquire position from Network.

**Small edit:** is it maybe any way to check GPS signal strength before using GPS or Network provider?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3551743/5094531 this might help

Comment: yes thanks! that can be helpful with the second part of the question!!

Comment: yeah..... working on first part :)

Answer (score 1):

[LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onStatusChanged(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) has a function `onStatusChanged()`. You have to override this function to check GPS_PROVIDER's status and accordingly take necessary action , which in your case is switching to NETWORK_PROVIDER.

Hope this answers your query

Comment: thanks for your answer, still need to figure out how to switch provider after GPS has been trying to acquire position for XXX seconds....maybe the best would be use `getBestProvider`and add a `Criteria`with a `speed`requirement??